# .animate in jQuery giving unexpected results

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm transfering a client's site from Flash to HTML, using jQuery to replicate the Flash animation's effects. This particular one uses .animate to change the value for "top" in CSS. All affected elements have their CSS position set to absolute or relative.

Here's the top-changing code:

```
function maskUp(height, length) {
    var contentMask = $('#left-content .content-mask');

    contentMask.animate({top: 312}, 500, function(){
        contentMask.delay(100).animate({top: height}, length, function(){
            contentMask.children('.active').removeClass('hide');
        });
    });
}
```

(edit: site address removed)

The animation works every time I hit Reload, however if I just select the address bar and hit Enter, when the animation completes, the element jumps to a completely different place than it's supposed to. Chrome's developer tools show that it has the correct value for "top", however it is in the wrong place, and changing the value in Chrome's developer tools doesn't change the position at all, making me think that I've broken it somehow.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so what the issue is (as far as I can tell)  is that it keeps jumping the viewport to the location of your `a-sorry-state` div.  If you pass an `id` as the `location.hash` of a page, it will scroll to that element with that `id`.  Thus, I would say use a query parameter instead of the hash part of the url.  Looking at your code in `tabs.js` I would say you could change the following function

```
function getHash( url ) {
    var hashPos = url.lastIndexOf ( '#' );
    return url.substring( hashPos + 1 );
}
```

to

```
/*might want to change the name too*/
function getHash() {
    return location.search.slice(1); // .search will return the part of the url
                                     // that follows the ? symbol. string.slice(1)
                                     // returns all but the first character of
                                     // the string (the ?).
}
```

And then use a url like

`http://panaceaentertainment.com/wp/television?a-sorry-state`

Comment: Ah, a jumping viewport would explain it. This sounds like a reasonable solution, however the reason I'm using the hash instead of a search query is so that the page doesn't load itself all over again when the user clicks a link. I will try changing up the hash tags so that no ID is the same as the hash.

Comment: @Gotcat As far as I know, search param wont cause a full reload either.  It should work the same

Comment: That's good to know, thanks Joseph! Although, I had changed around the hash tags before I read your reply and that fixed the problem (the viewport jumping was the issue). Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry no real answer for you, just something to look into.

Does it have anything to do with your lightbox?  I can see that the top style is different for your id="lightbox" when you reload vs. press enter on address bar.

What happens if you remove the lightbox code?

Comment: This has been happening on the site since before I added the lightbox code, and after removing it, the problem remains.